# Skip a part of the stream when it's stalled

Tags: akka-stream

I have a situation where messages are passed through a component that could possibly delay them.

Under stress I'd like to skip this component, so that no more than X messages could be delayed simultaneously. Overflowing messages will skip this stage and move to the next stage of the steam.

Messages are stalled within this stage till their future is done, or up to one minute, whichever comes first.

I can probably implement a custom GraphStage similarly [to this buffer example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html#rate-decoupled-operators), or use divertTo with some counter to cause messages to skip the stalled component,
but it feels like there might be an easier approach in akka streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around your use case and came up with a solution based on an `Akka Actor` representing a counter and an asynchronous map stage:

The idea being that up to `3` elements can be processed at any given time and that based on a counter whose max capacity is `2` we'd only allow at most `2` of these elements to simultaneously be processed by the slow component.

This way, there's always one thread of processing reserved to upstream elements that would be branched out from the slow component and directly reach downstream.

---

Let's first define a basic `Counter` with a maximum capacity as an `Akka Actor`:

```scala
class Counter(max: Int) extends Actor {
  private var count: Int = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TryAndLock if count < max =>
      count += 1
      sender ! true
    case TryAndLock =>
      sender ! false
    case Release =>
      count -= 1
  }
}

sealed trait CounterAction
case object TryAndLock extends CounterAction
case object Release extends CounterAction

val counter = system.actorOf(Props(new Counter(max = 2)))
```

It holds a mutable `count` variable that can be incremented via a `TryAndLock` request, but only if the count hasn't yet reached the maximum capacity, and can be decremented via a `Release` request.

We're using an `Actor` so that concurrent lock and release operations from within the following `mapAsync` stage are correctly handled without race conditions.

---

Then, it's just a matter of using a [`mapAsyncUnordered`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsyncUnordered.html) stage with a parallelism just 1 unit above the counter's max capacity.

Any element passing through the asynchronous stage will query the `Counter` to try and lock a resource. If a resource's been locked, then the element will be thrown into the slow component. If not, it will skip it. Elements are passed into the slow component until we reach the counter's max capacity, at which point any new element will be skipped until an element exits the slow component and releases a resource from the counter.

We can't simply use a [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html#mapasync) because elements would keep their upstream's order when existing the stage, making skipped elements wait for elements processed by the slow component to finish before being produced downstream. Thus the necessity to use the [`mapAsyncUnordered`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsyncUnordered.html) instead.

Let's define an example with at most 2 elements processed at the same time by the slow component and an asynchronous map whose parallelism is 3:

```scala
Source(0 to 15)
  .throttle(1, 50.milliseconds)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism = 3) { i =>
    (counter ? TryAndLock).map {
      case locked: Boolean if locked =>
        val result = slowTask(i)
        counter ! Release
        result
      case _ =>
        skipTask(i)
    }
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

with for instance these two functions that'll simulate the slow component (`slowTask`) and what to do when skipping the slow component (`skipTask`):

```scala
def slowTask(value: Int): String = {
  val start = Instant.now()
  Thread.sleep(250)
  s"$value - processed - $start - ${Instant.now()}"
}
def skipTask(value: Int): String =
  s"$value - skipped - ${Instant.now()}"
```

which results in something like:

```
2 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.410Z
3 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.468Z
4 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.518Z
5 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.569Z
1 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.356Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.611Z
0 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.356Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.611Z
8 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.719Z
9 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.769Z
10 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.819Z
6 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.618Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.869Z
12 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.919Z
7 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.669Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.921Z
14 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:20.019Z
15 - skipped - 2020-06-03T19:07:20.070Z
11 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.869Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:20.122Z
13 - processed - 2020-06-03T19:07:19.968Z - 2020-06-03T19:07:20.219Z
```

where the first part is the index of the upstream element, the second part is the transformation the element's been applied on (either `processed` when entering the slow component or `skipped`) and the last part is a timestamp so that we visualise when things are happening.

The 2 first elements entering the stage (0 and 1) are processed by the slow component and a bunch of following elements (2, 3, 4 and 5) are skipping the slow stage until these 2 first elements complete and additional elements can enter the slow stage. And so on.

Gilfoyle

Comment: this is very similar to what we ended up doing, did try using queue offer to move to another stream, but the performance was very poor, and there wasn't a clean way to check if the offer was successful.